# Why $('.classname') returns a jquery function?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Usually when I run `$(classname)` in chrome's developer console, it will usually return a list of relevant elements. (For example `$('.img-holder')` gives me `[<img src='https://example.com/image.jpg'>]`)

However when I run this

[image]

it returns a `jQuery.fn.init`

Here is the DOM elements:

[image]

Why the difference?

Comment: Do you have 221 elements on the page with the `tile-content` class? And what do you see if you expand `[0 ... 99]`? Perhaps this is just how Chrome handles the case where there are more than 100 elements to display.

Comment: Since you only show a fragment of your code it is hard to tell but it could be that since you do not close the </a> element, jQuery is reading everything else on the page as part of the the <a> element.

Comment: If you have at least 101 elements on your page, try `$('*:lt(100)')`  and then try `$('*:lt(101)')` to see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a page that does not have jQuery or jQuery has been set in *no conflict* mode where it does not register the `$` alias, `$` in the Chrome console is an alias for `document.querySelector`. See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#selector

If jQuery has registered the `$` alias, then it returns a `jQuery` instance (what you're seeing as `jQuery.fn.init`). See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

---

You may also be seeing an optimisation in Chrome's console where large arrays or *array-like-objects* (like `jQuery`) are paginated. Smaller arrays will be shown in full.

Answer (score 1):

The little snippet here works just as expected: it delivers the jquery object the first two times. In the third case the first DOM object is shown:

```js
$(function(){
console.log($('.one'));            // jquery object
console.log($('.tile-content'));   // jquery object
console.log($('.tile-content')[0]);// first matched DOM object
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
Some text,
  <a href="someurl.html" class="tile-content">the link to some url</a>,
  <a href="url2.html" class="tile-content">another link</a>
and some more text<br><br>(remember to swich on your web console)
</div>
```

Just noticed on my Chrome console that in the first two cases you actually see the jquery object (although it might just look like an ordinary array of DOM elements). My third `console.log` shows just the first matched DOM element. This time the object *is* just a simple DOM element.